# login an anonymous user forever in Firebase with React Native

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, logging

I'm doing a scheduler (calendar) app using React Native. You can add tasks to whatever day you want to do them. To store those tasks I'm using Firebase.
Now, I want that the tasks shown in each device are different. I though the best way to achieve this is logging the user anonymously (so that user doesn't have to sign up, which would be nonsense, in my opinion), and by doing so, only tasks owned by that user can show.
I have achieved signing up a new anonymous user (and I can see the new user in the project in Firebase web page). However, I'm struggling to make that logging last forever.

I had written this piece of code in the first function that my app renders:

```
useEffect(() => {
    auth.onAuthStateChanged(function (user) {
        if (user) {
            navigation.navigate("Home");
        } else {
            auth.signInAnonymously().then(navigation.navigate("Home"));
        }
    });
});
```

where `auth = firebase.auth()`. However, each time that I reload my app, a new user is created.

Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set RN persistence ?

```
import {
  initializeAuth,
  getReactNativePersistence,
} from 'firebase/auth/react-native'
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage'

export const auth = initializeAuth(app, {
  persistence: getReactNativePersistence(AsyncStorage),
})
```

Comment: You mean exporting ```auth = initializeAuth(app, {
  persistence: getReactNativePersistence(AsyncStorage),
})```
instead of
```export auth = firebase.auth()```?